# Should I use a graft or a seam when attaching sweater shoulders?

Tags: knitting

I'm putting together a knitted sweater. Should I graft the shoulders together or seam them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seam. The shoulders of a sweater are a high-stress area; the entire weight of the sweater hangs from them. A nice, solid seam gives a sturdy structure for that hanging. A graft - which is designed to be stretchy, just like the main fabric of the sweater - can result in droopy shoulders and stretched necklines. The excellent Techknitter wrote an [illustrated article](http://techknitting.blogspot.com/2011/09/my-sweater-slips-off-my-shoulders.html) about the importance of seaming sweater shoulders, with lots of detail and tips for different types of necklines.